# Ошибка: SSD no media 0 bytes

Tags: linux, windows, linux-mint, ssd

После установки Linux mint второй ос на диск F, этот самый диск перестал отображаться на винде. Линукс я давно снёс, но проблемма осталась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит в проводнике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен, если знающие люди обьяснят что произошло и как это решить.

Comment: Скрин через `gpartel live` в студию.

Comment: А SSD после сноса Linux Mint, был ли отформатирован в NTFS или FAT32?